# Spring MVC Binding from HTML form submission requires setters... but binding from JSON doesn't?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, binding

I have some RequestMapping 's in Spring Controllers.  Some of them receive JSON POST 's that are bound to a POJO using @RequestBody annotation, and some of them are submissions from an HTML web form.  In all of these cases I'm binding to the same object type.

All of this object's fields are private, and the object does not have the standard set...() methods, because I don't need them.  Or, I thought I didn't need them.

Unfortunately, in the case of the HTML form submission (Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded), the binding does not work properly unless I generate setter methods (object is created but the fields have null or default values).  Is there a way to avoid adding these methods that I don't need ONLY for the Spring MVC framework?

If there's no way to avoid it, I'm going to add a tiny bit of javascript to do my form submission as a JSON post, in order to get around this.

**How can I do this without adding setters to my POJO?**

Comment: Form parsing for model attribute parameters is done by following the JavaBeans convention. JSON parsing can be done the same if you're using Jackson, or through fields directly if you're using Gson. (Or other ways depending on what you're using.)

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're kind-of relying on your particular platform/JSON library's behavior, vs. Spring's form processing behavior. I'm more surprised that the JSON can parse without setters than that Spring can't.